# QEMU Not booting

Tags: qemu

Do qemu 5.1.0-dirty and qemu 5.1.0 versions behave differently?

No error occurs, but it boots with qemu 5.1.0-dirty version and not with 5.1.0. What could be the problem?

```
/home/pi/qemu/qemu-5.1.0/build/aarch64-softmmu/qemu-system-aarch64 -drive file=/home/pi/images/boot.qcow2,id=disk0,format=raw,if=none,cache=none -monitor null -object rng-random,filename=/dev/random,id=rng0 -cpu host -machine type=virt -device virtio-keyboard-pci -device virtio-rng-pci,rng=rng0 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=disk0 -serial mon:stdio -kernel /home/pi/kernel/Image-vdt -usb -nodefaults -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,mac=CA:FE:BA:BE:BE:EF,rombar=0 -netdev type=tap,id=net0,ifname=qemu_tap0,script=no,downscript=no -device virtio-gpu-pci,virgl,xres=1680,yres=560 -display sdl,gl=on -device virtio-tablet-pci -show-cursor -m 5G -smp 3 -device qemu-xhci,id=xhci -enable-kvm -append "root=/dev/vda9 ro loglevel=7 audit=0 enforcing=0 console=tty0 fbcon=map:10 video=1680x560-32 mem=5G"
```

Both versions used the same command line, but only booted
from the qemu 5.1.0-dirty version.

In qemu 5.1.0, which does not boot, the QEMU screen is created, but the phrase 'guest has not initialized the display (yet)' is displayed and it does not proceed any further.

5.1.0-dirty only exists in binaries, and version 5.1.0 was used after compiling the source code.

Use the compile options --enable-sdl --enable-gtk --target-list=aarch64-softmmu .

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyBih.png)

It should boot normally, but it doesn't.

What is the difference between qemu 5.1.0-dirty and regular qemu 5.1.0?

Answer (score 0):

-dirty on the end of a QEMU version string means "5.1.0 plus any number of unknown extra changes", i.e. it is not a clean upstream version. It could have absolutely anything in it. You would need to find out exactly where the binary came from and what sources it was built from to be able to find out what the differences are between it and a clean 5.1.0.